# GreenDao NoClassDefFoundError on DaoObject

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror, greendao, greendao-generator

I'm working on an Android app that has been created initially by someone else. This app is using GreenDao 2.0.0 to store objects from the API. Everything works fine on some devices (like Nexus 5) but for some reasons, it's not working on my Android 4.2 and 4.4 devices. The code compiles but when I want to launch my app it crashes and I get the following error :

11-04 16:26:35.951 6614-6614/com.myeggbox E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-04 16:26:35.951 6614-6614/com.myeggbox E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.myeggbox, PID: 6614
**11-04 16:26:35.951 6614-6614/com.myeggbox E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.myeggbox.api.data.entity.AddressDao

I never used GreenDao before so I'm lost, if someone has any idea ... In my build.gradle the targetSdk is 22 and the minSdkVersion is 16.
This is my EntityGenerator.java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Schema schema = new Schema(4, "com.myeggbox.api.data.entity");
    schema.enableKeepSectionsByDefault();

    //on init les Entity puis on les maps
    createEntities(schema);
    mapEntities();
    addRelationShip();

    new DaoGenerator().generateAll(schema, "../app/src/main/java/");
}

/*
** Init
 */
private static void createEntities(final Schema schema) {
    address = schema.addEntity("Address");
    brand = schema.addEntity("Brand");
    category = schema.addEntity("Category");
    code = schema.addEntity("Code");
    document = schema.addEntity("Document");
    egg = schema.addEntity("Egg");
    product = schema.addEntity("Product");
    review = schema.addEntity("Review");
    service = schema.addEntity("Service");
    user = schema.addEntity("User");
    store = schema.addEntity("Store");
}

private static void mapEntities() {
    addEgg();
    addCategory();
    addCode();
    addDocument();
    addProduct();
    addStore();
    addBrand();
    addService();
    addAddress();
    addReview();
    addUser();
}

private static void addRelationShip() {
    //egg <-> user
    Property egg_user_id = egg.addLongProperty("user_id").getProperty();
    egg.addToOne(user, egg_user_id).setName("userDb");//liaison vers l'utilisateur
    user.addToMany(egg, egg_user_id).setName("eggListDb");//liaison inverse

    //egg <-> product
    Property egg_product_id = egg.addLongProperty("product_id").getProperty();
    egg.addToOne(product, egg_product_id).setName("productDb");//liaison vers le product
    product.addToMany(egg, egg_product_id).setName("eggListDb");//liaison inverse

    //code <-> egg
    Property code_egg_id = code.addLongProperty("egg_id_db").getProperty();
    code.addToOne(egg, code_egg_id).setName("eggDb");//liaison du code vers l'egg
    egg.addToMany(code, code_egg_id).setName("codeListDb");//liaison inverse

    //code <-> user
    Property code_user_id = code.addLongProperty("user_id").getProperty();
    code.addToOne(user, code_user_id).setName("userDb");
    user.addToMany(code, code_user_id).setName("codeListDb");

    //documents <-> egg
    Property doc_egg_id = document.addLongProperty("egg_id").getProperty();
    document.addToOne(egg, doc_egg_id).setName("eggDb");//liaison vers l'egg
    egg.addToMany(document, doc_egg_id).setName("documentListDb");//liaison inverse

    //egg <-> store
    Property egg_store_id = egg.addLongProperty("store_id").getProperty();
    egg.addToOne(store, egg_store_id).setName("storeDb");//relation vers l'egg
    store.addToMany(egg, egg_store_id).setName("eggListDb");//relation inverse

    //product <-> brand
    Property product_brand_id = product.addLongProperty("brand_id").getProperty();
    product.addToOne(brand, product_brand_id).setName("brandDb");//liaison vers le product
    brand.addToMany(product, product_brand_id).setName("productListDb");//liaison inverse

    //product <-> category
    Property product_category_id = product.addLongProperty("category_id").getProperty();
    product.addToOne(category, product_category_id).setName("categoryDb");//liaison vers la category
    category.addToMany(product, product_category_id).setName("productListDb");//liaison inverse

    //service <-> egg
    Property service_egg_id = service.addLongProperty("egg_local_id").getProperty();
    service.addToOne(egg, service_egg_id);//relation vers l'egg
    egg.addToMany(service, service_egg_id).setName("serviceListDb");//relation inverse

    //review <-> product
    Property review_product_id = review.addLongProperty("product_id").getProperty();
    review.addToOne(product, review_product_id).setName("productDB");//liaison vers le product
    product.addToMany(review, review_product_id).setName("reviewListDb");//liaison inverse

    //address <-> user
    Property address_user_id = address.addLongProperty("user_id").getProperty();
    address.addToOne(user, address_user_id).setName("userDB");//liaison vers le user
    user.addToMany(address, address_user_id).setName("addressListDb");//liaison inverse
}

/*
** Maping des modéles
 */
private static void addEgg() {
    egg.implementsInterface("Serializable", "Comparable<Egg>");
    egg.addLongProperty("localId").primaryKey().autoincrement();
    egg.addStringProperty("buying_date");
    egg.addLongProperty("id");
    egg.addStringProperty("picture");
    egg.addIntProperty("warranty_duration");
    egg.addStringProperty("created_at");
    egg.addStringProperty("localPicture");
}

private static void addCode() {
    code.implementsInterface("Serializable");
    code.addLongProperty("localId").primaryKey().autoincrement();
    code.addLongProperty("id");
    code.addStringProperty("digest");
}

private static void addDocument() {
    document.implementsInterface("Serializable");
    document.addLongProperty("localId").primaryKey().autoincrement();
    document.addStringProperty("content");
    document.addStringProperty("created_at");
    document.addLongProperty("id");
    document.addStringProperty("picture");
    document.addStringProperty("preview");
    document.addStringProperty("title");
    document.addStringProperty("UUID");
    document.addStringProperty("updated_at");
    document.addStringProperty("localPath");
    document.addStringProperty("type");
}

private static void addStore() {
    store.implementsInterface("Serializable");
    store.addLongProperty("localId").primaryKey().autoincrement();
    store.addLongProperty("id");
    store.addStringProperty("name");
    store.addStringProperty("phone");
    store.addStringProperty("email");
    store.addStringProperty("website");
    store.addStringProperty("street_name");
    store.addStringProperty("city");
    store.addStringProperty("zip_code");
    store.addStringProperty("country");
    store.addStringProperty("facebook_url");
    store.addStringProperty("logo");
    store.addStringProperty("latitude");
    store.addStringProperty("longitude");
}

private static void addProduct() {
    product.implementsInterface("Serializable");
    product.addLongProperty("localId").primaryKey().autoincrement();
    product.addLongProperty("id");
    product.addStringProperty("name");
    product.addStringProperty("picture");
    product.addStringProperty("ean");
}

private static void addBrand() {
    brand.implementsInterface("Serializable");
    brand.addLongProperty("localId").primaryKey().autoincrement();
    brand.addLongProperty("id");
    brand.addStringProperty("name");
}

private static void addCategory() {
    category.implementsInterface("Serializable");
    category.addLongProperty("localId").primaryKey().autoincrement();
    category.addLongProperty("id");
    category.addStringProperty("image");
    category.addStringProperty("name");
}

private static void addService() {
    service.implementsInterface("Serializable");
    service.addLongProperty("localId").primaryKey().autoincrement();
    service.addLongProperty("id");
    service.addStringProperty("kind");
    service.addStringProperty("phone");
    service.addStringProperty("title");
    service.addStringProperty("web_url");
    service.addStringProperty("local_path");
}

private static void addUser() {
    user.implementsInterface("Serializable");
    user.addLongProperty("localId").primaryKey().autoincrement();
    user.addStringProperty("id");
    user.addStringProperty("email");
    user.addStringProperty("authentication_token");
}

private static void addAddress() {
    address.implementsInterface("Serializable");
    address.addLongProperty("localId").primaryKey().autoincrement();
    address.addStringProperty("city");
    address.addStringProperty("country");
    address.addStringProperty("firstname");
    address.addLongProperty("id");
    address.addStringProperty("lastname");
    address.addStringProperty("street_name");
    address.addStringProperty("zip_code");
}

private static void addReview() {
    review.implementsInterface("Serializable");
    review.addLongProperty("localId").primaryKey().autoincrement();
    review.addStringProperty("content");
    review.addStringProperty("created_at");
    review.addLongProperty("id");
    review.addStringProperty("locale");
    review.addIntProperty("rate");
    review.addStringProperty("title");
    review.addStringProperty("upload_at");
    review.addIntProperty("user_id");
}
```

}

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

This is not an Android class, and it should not run as part of Android.

1. You should compile this class as an usual java file 
   ( Like $javac EntityGenerator.java )
2. Then Run the class $java EntityGenerator, after it finished
   check the ../app/src/main/java/ directory, you should have there the Dao generated files to access your database.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but unfortunately I tried to compile the EntityGenerator.java like you said but I still get the error on my 4.1.1 device. I don't get any error while running the EntityGenerator and my classes are generated, I checked. The error occurs when running the app, not the EntityGenerator

Comment: @MeganLeBerre are the generated classes in the source-folder of your android project?